# selenium chrome webdriver error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

i hit this error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. while running the chrome. 
Any advise please? for full error message is at bottom of my post.

OS: Windows 10
Eclipse: Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211
Chrome:  Version 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chrome web driver: Version 81.0.4044.69

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");    
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
         driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Error message output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 39285
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, chromeOptions=org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions@acf6a1bc, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-TQC1N01', ip: '192.168.0.102', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:156)
    at testscript.test.main(test.java:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried below code, If you are using chrome browser version 81.0.4044.92 then downgrade your ChromeDriver to  80.0.3987.106 and give a try. This issue occurs due to compability between your browser and chromedriver. I think you are using selenium grid jar[Unable to create new remote session]. you haave to use Latest stable version 3.141.59

I have checked same solution and its working fine for me without any issue.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"," path of chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for yr help, i have given a try on chrome driver 80.0.3987.106, apparently, it the same error.

Comment: I think you are using selenium grid jar[Unable to create new remote session].  you haave to use Latest stable version 3.141.59 (https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

Comment: Thanks dipak! the error is gone, i able to get the chrome driver started thanks!

Comment: Can you please accept my answer and hit upvote button